# How can external clients store xml-files?

Tags: xml, communication

I am currently designing a system where I have the following problem:

I have a webapplication, running on an own Windows server. And i have an external client who has to communicate with the webapplication. The communication will go through XML files. The client is making one XML-file with some data which the application has to read and process. My problem is that I have no idea if there are best practises for this problem.

I am thinking about the following solution for this problem: The client is sending the XML-file to a directory on the server. This directory is being watched by the application and when a new XML-file is being added, an event occurs and the application knows that there is a new file and is going to read it and process the data. When data processing is finished, the application will remove the XML file.

Is this the best solution or are there other solution for this 'problem'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the solution by "The client is sending the XML-file to a directory on the server.", you do not need webapplication. It can be just any application running on a server.

It has many ways to implement this with webapplication.
  - if your client is nut human, you can write a page in your webapp to upload file
  - if your client can be an application, you can write to upload xml to your webapp (from webapp perspective, it is the same code as above). You just need to know how to write program (for client) to connect like a browser and upload a file.

Any of two solutions, you have to know how to write webapplication to be able to read uploaded file.

Comment: Okay Thanks for the reply. The XML-reading part is only a part of the application. Thats why i need an webapplication. But You dont know if there are best practises for this in terms of security or that there are standard ways to do thinks like this?

Comment: I think the security issue is out of scope here. It is too big issue and it depends on how you will implement the solution.